# Is it possible to write an excel macro to find and replace a large number of text strings in that are only found in a column with a particular header?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a macro to run a large number if find and replace as a way to abbreviate addresses. The files that I am running this on have the address field in no set column or location. I am having difficulty getting a macro to first find the column with the name that I want and then run the find and replaces on specifically just that column.

I have searched all around and found a method for finding the column that I am looking for (in the example, it is set as "ADDRESS 1") and then run find and replace macros that I have also found. However, when I combined the two macros into one(probably incorrectly), it selects the correct columns, then runs the find and replace on the entire sheet anyway. See my current code (I am a complete amateur when it comes to this sort of thing so any explanation would be helpful)

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRgUni As Range
    Dim xFirstAddress As String
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "ADDRESS 1"
    Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)

    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If

    xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select

    Set myrange = ActiveWorkbook.xRgUni.EntireColumn.Select

    fndList = Array(" PLAZA ", " CIRCLE ")
    rplcList = Array(" PLZ. ", " CIR. ")

    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next sht

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: For any given worksheet, will all the strings to be processed be in the same column? Or might you have multiple columns to process on the same worksheet?

Comment: The text that I am looking to replace should be only in the column of the search. and there should never be more than one column with that particular name.

Comment: For clarification, the desire is for all of the find and replace actions to run ONLY in the column whose top bar is labeled as "ADDRESS 1"(regardless of the location of this column in the document). Instances of those text strings in columns without that header should be ignored by the macro.

Comment: Then all you should need to do is search that particular column:  Something like `intersect(sht.UsedRange,xrg.Columns(1).entirecolumn).Replace( …)`

Comment: Would this work if the Address 1 column is located in various locations? Also, would this method limit the number of replace statements that can be written in? My current use of the find list and replace list is used because I want the ability to replace large numbers of incorrect text with others. Again, sorry if these are basic questions, Im pretty new to this.

Comment: `Address 1` column can be any place. And since the cell is only a single cell, `Columns(1)` will always refer to the relevant column.  And you just need to repeat the `.Replace` for as many pairs as you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here since this is copy/paste type of code. But one of those assumptions is that `xRgUni` is in fact the range in which the header you are searching for was found. If that's true then this should work:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fndList As Variant
    Dim rplcList As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRgUni As Range
    Dim xFirstAddress As String
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = "ADDRESS 1"
    Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").Find(xStr, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)

    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xFirstAddress = xRg.Address
        Do
            Set xRg = Range("A1:P1").FindNext(xRg)
            If xRgUni Is Nothing Then
                Set xRgUni = xRg
            Else
                Set xRgUni = Application.Union(xRgUni, xRg)
            End If
        Loop While (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xRg.Address <> xFirstAddress)
    End If

    xRgUni = xRgUni.EntireColumn

    fndList = Array(" PLAZA ", " CIRCLE ")
    rplcList = Array(" PLZ. ", " CIR. ")

    'Loop through all find/replace combos
    For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
        'Loop through each sheet in the workbook
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            'For the column defined by xRgUni in this sheet, do the find/replace
            sht.Range(xRgUni.AddressLocal).Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next sht

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: When I tested this update to the code it actually just removed the text of "ADDRESS 1" from the header and made no other changes.

Comment: This works. Thanks so much! it appears that the removal of the top item of the column is still reoccurring. I think that i can resolve that on my own though.

Comment: I haven't tried this, bit I wonder if you could do `sht.Range(xRgUni.EntireColumn.Offset(,1).AddressLocal)...`